# AWS Cloudfront to my web server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Is there a way to point an AWS Cloudfront instance to my own personal web server not hosted in AWS. So it's not an EC2 or a ELB instance. It's a custom web server hosted with another host. Is this possible? I can't seem to configure this an origin?

Comment: Have you read through the CloudFront docs on the subject?  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes, You can do that. When creating distribution, In the Origin Settings section specify your domain as the "Origin".

[image]

Suppose you want make CloudFront for `example.com` Do the following steps:

1) Create a subdomain for your application `us.example.com`

2) Create distribution with the Origin to `us.example.com` it will give you a domain name like this `d2uhnp5egk65ug.cloudfront.net`

3) adjust settings for your naked domain to point to your cloud front distribution `d2uhnp5egk65ug.cloudfront.net`.

Now by using `CNAME` `example.com` can point to distribution `d2uhnp5egk65ug.cloudfront.net` that might have multiple origins in the backend like "`us.example.com`" and "`uk.example.com`"

Comment: Do note that a non AWS origin is priced differently, so be sure to check https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/ so that you know what you're getting into

Comment: @ChrisWhite no, it isn't.  What specific element in the CloudFront pricing page is leading you to that conclusion?

Comment: Maybe you're seeing *"If you are using an AWS origin, effective December 1, 2014, data transferred from origin to edge locations (Amazon CloudFront "origin fetches") will be free of charge."*  It was already free for an external origin.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Looking back that was a bad place to link to, but for example [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) and [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) out to CloudFront are free. However, if you're at XYZ hosting that charges X for transfer out you're going to have to deal with those costs when CloudFront goes to fetch from that origin (depending on TTL).

Comment: @ChrisWhite yes, there could be 3rd party costs if the origin server provider's network charges you for bandwidth out (though CloudFront caching could reduce this by eliminating some redundant requests to the origin.) Your comment seemed to imply a difference in the AWS pricing for such an arrangement.